# Is it possible to return Stream<?> from JAX-RS 2.1 resource?

Tags: jax-rs, java-stream, resteasy, java-ee-8

Googling surprisingly did not show results! So, please, I am wondering if it is possible...:
1. as for any JAX-RS implementation (e.g. by spec) - did not find that one in the spec itself. 
2. as for some particular one (like a provider specific capability, I am currently on RestEasy btw)
3. and if yes, should I close the stream of, say, it came from hibernate scrollable result e.g. Session#stream()? Or does JAX-RS closes automatically or at least because as I remember all Collections etc. are represented as Lists in JAX-RS?

I believe I saw it somewhere in 2.1 presentation on SlideShare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is supported as of JAX-RS 2.1 for sure.

For serializing response bodies a SNAPSHOT of "currently-in-development" `jackson-jaxrs-X-provider` can be used which at the time of writing this post could only be locally built with maven from relevant FasterXML repository. All other needed components except just `jackson-jaxrs-X-provider` of Jackson 3.x (like `jackson core`, `jackson-annotations`, etc.) are available in OSS SNAPSHOT repo.

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/fasterxml/

Tried it, it works fine.